# VBA Excel: Run-time error 13 type mismatch due to too many characters

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a 'dashboard' in excel where the user can select a commodity and then presses the run button, so the code then prints out all suppliers linked to that commodity. (Several commodities and supplier names are listed on other tabs in the same workbook, and the code goes over all tabs to collect the right supplier names)

**EDIT: the issue is due to a supplier name being longer than 255 characters.**

The debugger focuses on this code in particular:

```
If Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & myDataRng.Address & "," & cell.Address & ")") > 1 Then
    cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbRed
End If
```

This code is part of the bigger set below. The code highlights all suppliernames that are listed under the chosen category in different tabs (hence they would be printed out multiple times, I want to highlight the duplicate values).

```
'##### Find duplicates in commodity column and highlight them ######

Dim myDataRng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set myDataRng = Range("E10:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cell In myDataRng
    cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbBlack


    If Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & myDataRng.Address & "," & cell.Address & ")") > 1 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next cell
```

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not immediately obvious. I made a few tweaks to the code, however this should allow you to see what's being evaluated. Typically you'd get this error from the formula not being entered with the correct format, but it works on my end.

I removed the Offset(0,0) as it is superfluous at present with no offset applied, as well as placing the vbBlack formatting in an Else block for performance/clarity.

However seeing the Debug.Print statement should be critical for understanding when the code is not functioning. The only other thought I have, is you may want to clarify which sheet this Countif is being completed on.

**Update**

I've revised my answer to use SumProduct instead of CountIf to workaround the issue of 255 characters being the limit for CountIf.

```
Public Sub TestSub()
    Dim myDataRng       As Range
    Dim cell            As Range
    Dim EvalStr         As String

    Set myDataRng = Range("E10:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell In myDataRng
        EvalStr = "SumProduct((" & myDataRng.Address & "=" & cell.Address & ")+0)"
        If Application.Evaluate(EvalStr) > 1 Then
            cell.Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code - still same issues. It works on all other commodities except this one in particular. I'm going to do some more digging myself - this is odd. I entered the commodity the same way as all others in that one tab..

Comment: What is the myDataRng.Address? What did the Debug.Print EvalStr print out?

Comment: This is what I got: COUNTIF($E$10:$E$49,$E$10)
COUNTIF($E$10:$E$49,$E$11)
COUNTIF($E$10:$E$49,$E$12)
and so on till COUNTIF($SE$:$E$49,$E$49)

Comment: Are any of the cell values you are using as the criteria longer than 255 characters? I believe this is a limitation with Countif. There's a way to get around this with using SumProduct I believe.

Comment: I believe that is indeed the issue. There is one supplier name of 304 characters. i tested whether the other commodities linked to that supplier name run same error code and indeed they do! Now I need to get around it. You suggest to simply replace COUNTIF with SumProduct?

Comment: @Jolien.A, yes. I've updated my answer with the change from countif to Sumproduct. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your line:

```
If Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & myDataRng.Address & "," & cell.Address & ")") > 1 Then
```

With:

```
 If Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & myDataRng.Address & "," & cell.Address & " > 1 )") Then
```

Comment: This removed the error - but now the code does not color the duplicate values red anymore